# Как установить размер окна скрипта Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

как сделать,чтобы при открытии скрипт разворачивался на весь экран,а не открывался в окне?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.